# MySQL - Execute Select and Delete in different queries?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was wondering how would go about executing two different queries like this:

```
    if ($uresult->num_rows >0) {


 while($urow = $uresult->fetch_assoc()) {


 $rresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM allid WHERE postid='$oldid' AND spaceid='$newid'");
 $rresult = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM allid WHERE postid AND spaceid IS NULL");
 $lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult);
 $tem = $lrow['postid'];

 $ujson = json_encode($tem);
 echo $ujson;
 }

} else {
}
```

I know `mysqli_fetch` can't hold no more than one query and there are similar questions, but I can't seem to understand the answers from the other questions. If there is a question that solves this question, I apologize and will delete this one.

Comment: you use `$rresult` for both queries, just change one .. solved (you dont even need to assign the delete one to a var

Answer (score 1):

all other things being equal, simple dont overwrite the `$rresult`  from select with delete:

```
if ($uresult->num_rows >0) {

    while($urow = $uresult->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
                                      FROM allid 
                                      WHERE postid='$oldid' 
                                      AND spaceid='$newid'");
        mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM allid 
                           WHERE postid AND spaceid IS NULL");
        $lrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rresult);
        $tem = $lrow['postid'];

        $ujson = json_encode($tem);
        echo $ujson;
    }

} else {
}
```

Comment: Ok, I deleted the variable and the second query is not deleting the null from the results. Does placement matter? @smith

Comment: @LaneyWilliams did you mean to write `WHERE postid IS NULL AND spaceid IS NULL` ?

Comment: I believe so and I just tested that. Here is what I am getting: `"10"nullnullnullnullnullnull"202"`

Comment: you are deleting after you select, did you mean to do it the other way around?

Comment: Oh no. I just want to remove those `null` from the results above. I looked up other answers and they said to use `IS NULL`.

Comment: im confused do you want to remove from the database, or not show in the results of the select query?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just want it to not show in the results of the select query.

Comment: remove the delete now, before you damage your db, will update query above for the exclusions in the select

Comment: your current where clause should mean that its impossible to select rows where  `postid` or `spaceid` is NULL. are you sure `$oldid` and `$newid` are populated?

Comment: Yes they are populated. I think since I am working with json, those empty values will show up as null and display. When I do it without json_encoding, all you see are those values. If they are empty then you wouldn't see anything.

Comment: is 10 and 202 from above the values for  `postid` and `spaceid` ?

Comment: They are values from `postid` from echoing `$lrow['postid'];`

Comment: that's a single db field with `"10"nullnullnullnullnullnull"202"` in it ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Also, if it is impossible to remove those `null` from the result. I just need to figure out to place commas between the values.

Comment: the fundamental issue here is database normalisation, you should have septate db columns for each value. sticking them all together like you have, is why you are now having such issues now. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Ahh I see. So is there a way I can add commas in the Select Query?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple queries that either rely on a result of a previous query or need to be run in order and each successfully run, you could use transactions. With transactions if one of the queries fails, you can roll back the transaction.